# обработка исключений в Task

Tags: c#, исключения, task

Есть такой код вызова асинхронной операции

```
Canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (
            () =>
            {
                try
                {                        
                    using (Canceller.Token.Register(Thread.CurrentThread.Abort))
                    {

                        while (1 == 1)
                            Thread.Sleep(200);                            
                    }
                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException EX)
                {

                }
            }
            , Canceller.Token
        );        
        AsyncExec.Exec
        (
            task, m_rootControl, "Применение групповых политик..."
        );


private static async void exec(Task _asyncAction, FrameworkElement _pageElement, string _text)
{
    try
    {
        if (_asyncAction != null)
        {
            await _asyncAction;
            //_asyncAction.Wait();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception _ex)
    {}
}
```

Так вот непонятка в следующем. 
Когда вызывается Canceller.Cancel(), дергается метод Abort() для асинхронного потока. Как надо ловится исключение ThreadAbortException. До этого момента все понятно. Но вот почему потом это же исключение ловится в  catch (Exception _ex), в блоке вызова асинхронного метода?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThreadAbortException` работает своеобразно. Если вы перехватываете его блоком `catch`, и не вызываете `Thread.ResetAbort`, тогда `CLR` выбрасывает его снова.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadabortexception?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

> ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block.